# SMTP: An error occurred while sending the message

Tags: mailcore2

I have Gmail working in my iOS app via OAuth and IMAP/SMTP. If I use another account though the SMTP won't work. I've tried with a email account on a custom domain (through Host Gator) and with an outlook.com account. IMAP works fine, it's just sending that fails. I have checked connection logger and get the following:

```
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 0 withData: 220 BLU436-SMTP189.smtp.hotmail.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 8.0.9200.16384 ready at  Wed, 7 Jan 2015 04:03:35 -0800 

event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 1 withData: EHLO -iPad

event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 0 withData: 250-BLU436-SMTP189.smtp.hotmail.com Hello [80.194.198.170]

250-TURN

250-SIZE 41943040

250-ETRN

250-PIPELINING

250-DSN

250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES

250-8bitmime

250-BINARYMIME

250-CHUNKING

250-VRFY

250-TLS

250-STARTTLS

250 OK

event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 1 withData: STARTTLS

event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 0 withData: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready

event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 1 withData: EHLO -iPad

event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 0 withData: 250-BLU436-SMTP189.smtp.hotmail.com Hello [80.194.198.170]

250-TURN

250-SIZE 41943040

250-ETRN

250-PIPELINING

250-DSN

250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES

250-8bitmime

250-BINARYMIME

250-CHUNKING

250-VRFY

250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2

250 OK

event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 2 withData: AUTH PLAIN a21jZ3JhZHlAb3V0bG9vay5jb20Aa21jZ3JhZHlAb3V0bG9vay5jb20AQWZ0ZXJlZmZlY3RzMT8=

event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 0 withData: 235 2.7.0 Authentication succeeded

event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 1 withData: MAIL FROM:<myemail@outlook.com>

event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 0 withData: 250 2.1.0 myemail@outlook.com....Sender OK

event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 1 withData: RCPT TO:<email@invalid.com>

event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 0 withData: 250 2.1.5 email@invalid.com 

event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 1 withData: MAIL FROM:<myemail@outlook.com> SIZE=799

event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 0 withData: 503 5.5.2 Sender already specified

event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 1 withData: QUIT

event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData: 
event logged:0x18141580 -1 withData:
```

My SMTP settings are:

Email

Password

Port 25 (also tried 587)

MCOConnectionTypeStartTLS (also tried MCOConnectionTypeTLS)

MCOAuthTypeSASLNone

In sendOperationWithData: I get the following error: `Error Domain=MCOErrorDomain Code=30 "An error occured while sending the message."`

This is the code to send:

```
  MCOAddress *address= [MCOAddress addressWithDisplayName:currentAccount.name mailbox:smtp_email];

MCOSMTPOperation * op = [currentSMTPSession checkAccountOperationWithFrom:address];
        [op start:^(NSError * error) {

            }
```

And I configure the SMTP (called before the send operation) like this:

```
    if (currentSMTPSession == nil) {
    currentSMTPSession = [[MCOSMTPSession alloc] init];
}

[currentSMTPSession setHostname:currentAccount.smtp_server];
[currentSMTPSession setUsername:currentAccount.smtp_email];
[currentSMTPSession setPassword:currentAccount.smtp_password];
[currentSMTPSession setPort:currentAccount.smtp_port.intValue];
[currentSMTPSession setConnectionType:MCOConnectionTypeStartTLS];
[currentSMTPSession setOAuth2Token:currentAccount.oauthToken];
[currentSMTPSession setAuthType:MCOAuthTypeSASLNone]
```

Comment: Don't use -checkAccountOperationWithFrom:

Comment: Currently I'm calling ```sendOperationWithData``` if ```checkAccountOperationWithFrom:``` has no error. Should I just call ```sendOperationWithData``` without the checkAccount?

Comment: Yes. That's what I'm advising.

Comment: Ok, I'm still getting an error: ```"A stable connection to the server could not be established"``` in the ```sendOperationWithData:``` operation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with the connection type. When I created the account I was saving the connection type returned using `MCONetService`. The person who worked on the code base before me was saving the IMAP connection type instead of the SMTP connection type. I changed this and now it works.

I also followed @DinhVietHoá's advice and removed `checkAccountOperationWithForm:`.